# How can I get my money back, they gave me a fake ethereum token help

Tags: ropsten

I was scammed 3hrs ago with ropsten test, I was buying an ethereum but the scammer gave me fake one. Can someone provide an option on how can I get my money back?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, but unfortunately in your case, this is a decentralized ecosystem and there is no 'support team' to help with transaction mistakes or sending funds to a malicious actor.

You can try and message this malicious actor and ask for your money back, which is unlikely. Sorry to hear about this